# Compute Engine Instance connection from browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Our users with following permission are unable to connect to the compute engine instance through browser based ssh. This only works for the users with project OWNER permission. This was working fine previously (in dev project). What's the change in regards to this? What is the best way to grant connectivity to prod support team without making them the project owner.

Compute Admin,
Compute Instance Admin (beta),
Compute Network User,
Compute OS Admin Login,
Compute OS Login

Comment: not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users will need `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1` to use SSH from `gcloud` or the browser.

[Connecting to an instance as an instanceAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#connectinginstanceadmin)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Here is the list of steps I followed after going this and related links. May be not all steps listed here are required, 1. Add User Account with following permission
 Compute Instance Admin (v1)
 Compute Network User
 Compute OS Login
 Service Account User

2.  Service Account
 a. create service account : <user_id>@...
 b.  grant role of "Compute Engine -> Compute Instance Admin (v1)"
 c. Add all users who needs access to instance under this service account

3. SSH key 
 Add ssh key to GCE instance on which need access.